Hungarian Immigration wrote a code on my passport
I hold a Turkish passport along with an EU residency permit from the Netherlands. Recently, I traveled from Amsterdam to Serbia, and then to Budapest. Upon entering Hungary, the passport control officer wrote a code (“XXXX1X1X1”) with her pen on my passport without asking any questions, and I was allowed entry without issue.
During my travel, my flight from Serbia was canceled, which required me to exit the departures zone and pass through Serbian passport control twice. I am wondering if this could have led to the code being written on my passport, or if there could be another reason for this notation.
Could you please provide some insight into the meaning of this code and if it relates to my travel circumstances?

Case closed: it was my residence card id number on the top right corner in the front  of the card. thank you guys for your answers.

Where did she write the code --- on a visa page?  Is the code by any chance the document number of your residence permit?  They do have nine characters, and some images I've seen online have codes starting with "V."

Can you clarify where/when this happened? It’s not completely clear from your story if that happened in Serbia before your (complicated) departure or in Hungary after you landed. Also, did you get a stamp?

@phoog she wrote it right on where stamped, just right above the stamp.

@jcaron i’m sure it happened while i was entering hungary because I literally saw passport police when she was writing the code on my passport. She wrote just right above where she stamped it.

@mmm, please accept the answer by duke, by clicking the tick to the left.

I believe it should be the number of your Dutch residence permit. Hungarian police is seen to annotate the entry stamps with people entering with residence permits of Schengen States.

it was, I first looked at the long nr in the back and then I noticed it was actually the number on the front of the card on top right corner.
